# UIAlertcontroller in TextfieldShouldBeginediting objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I want to show alert before text enter in textfield after ok button click textfield will be editable but I am showing alert but textfield did not editable.

```
if(textField == contractValueField)
{
    [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Information" textfield:contractValueField];
    return YES;
}
```

I search so many sites but I did not get right answer by using UIAlertView it is working but I want to use UIAlertController. I have more than 20 textfields in my project & every textfield I will show alert before edit begin.

```
- (void)showAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title textfield:(UITextField*)textfield
{
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:@"Please enter Amount in Lakhs" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
    {
        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        [textfield becomeFirstResponder];
    }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: is your showAlertWithTitle:  method gets called?.

Comment: yes, it is calling but textfield did not editable after press ok

Comment: try just [self presentViewController], I think that's it is not working

Comment: No it is not working

Comment: Try adding becomeFirstResponder in the completion block of dismissViewController

Comment: [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; it is not required   and  [textfield becomeFirstResponder]; is must be call after press ok so it will on UIAlertAction method only

Comment: [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [textfield becomeFirstResponder];
    }];

Comment: Is the alert shown again once you press the ok button?

Comment: no i don't want to show alert again i want to edit the textfield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that when you call `[textfield becomeFirstResponder]`, `-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` is also called again, which in turn shows your alertView, and when the ok button is selected from your alert, the alert view is shown again, and you are stuck in a loop. Here is a quick way to fix it:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    // check to see if the alert has already been shown, if it has the tag value will be 1
    if (textField == contractValueField && textField.tag != 1) {
        [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Information" textfield:textField];
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The code for your alertView should be as follows:

```
- (void)showAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title textfield:(UITextField*)textfield{
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:@"Please enter Amount in Lakhs" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
        textfield.tag = 1;
        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        [textfield becomeFirstResponder];
    }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:true completion:nil];
}
```

Return the tag value of textField back to 0 when editing is finished:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    textField.tag = 0;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: first time it is showing alert i will edit the text also but i click another textfield then return &  click this textfield it didnot show alert. I want to show every time textfield will clicked the alert will show then edit.

Comment: Thank You very much it is working. Is there another way we can do without tags like -  textfield.selcted=yes;

Comment: I have one other idea, I'll add it as another answer

Answer (score 0):

Declare a UITextField which will reference the last selected textField:

```
@interface ViewController (){
    UITextField *lastSelectedTextField;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    // check to see if the textField is the last shown textField
    if (textField == lastSelectedTextField) {
        return true;
    }
    [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Information" textfield:textField];
    return false;
 }


- (void)showAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title textfield:(UITextField*)textfield{
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:@"Please enter Amount in Lakhs" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
        lastSelectedTextField = textfield;;
        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        [textfield becomeFirstResponder];
    }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:true completion:nil];
}
```

This would be the better option, I didn't realise that you wanted to show the alert every even if the textField had been selected previously

Comment: but i will not able to used this code because i have some textfields will return false;

Comment: I think you should be able to add another `else if()` statement to `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` to get around that, but it's a bit hard to help any further without learning more about your project and how it functions...

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answers. i tried another if else () it is working.

Comment: No worries at all